# Select CELL in a COLUMN; Text Box returns values of other CELLS from that ROW

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to be able to Select a CELL (Focus or Activate) and then to have other ActiveX Text Boxes return values from CELLS in the ROW of the SELECTED CELL.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AYaV.png)
So, if I selected CELL B4, then the 3 text boxes would show the values from F4, G4 and H4.

Possible?

Thank you!

Nothing attempted yet.  This is first time I thought of trying something like this.

Comment: Like `textbox1.value = ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).value` ? Totally possible. If you hit a snag coding this, then that would make for a good question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Save the code in worksheet module (right click sheet tab > view code > paste the code)
- The textboxes are populated when users select a cell in column B and row number is greater than 1 (skip the table header)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And .Column = 2 And .Row > 1 Then
            Me.TextBox1.Value = .Offset(0, 4).Value
            Me.TextBox2.Value = .Offset(0, 5).Value
            Me.TextBox3.Value = .Offset(0, 6).Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Worksheet.SelectionChange event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Offset property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.CountLarge property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144247)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Absolutely PERFECT!!!!!!

Comment: Would you mind explaining to a layman how the code works?
  - What does ByVal Target As Range do?  Is it telling it that when I select something (the target) that is the thing to reference (Range)?  - What is the .CountLarge doing?   -  ME. is that changing the focus do do something regarding the Target.   - What is the .Offset? Is that counting the columns?

Comment: Please refer to MS doc in my answer.